# How to implement time-based scheduled jobs like run at 12 AM in Play Framework 2.6?

Tags: playframework, akka, quartz-scheduler, playframework-2.6

The description will be long and detailed, please bear with it.

I want to make a scheduled job in my `play-framework 2.6` application which runs at a certain time everyday, say, 12 AM for instance.
As someone who hasn't worked in `akka`, I dug around and found some solutions.
Apparently, `akka` doesn't give the functionality to schedule a job like that, we can assign timer kind of jobs using `akka` i.e. run this every 6 hours or something.

I found out that there's the [akka quartz scheduler](https://github.com/enragedginger/akka-quartz-scheduler), but I couldn't find any example/implementation of it with `play framework 2.6`.

I also read [this](https://blog.knoldus.com/code-dissection-akka-quartz-scheduler-scalas-way-of-scheduling/) but it gave errors for some reason.

Finally I decided to change my solution and use a timer-based method, described in the [Play! ScheduledTasks documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScheduledTasks).
 I made a new package in my `play 2.6` app, and added classes `MyActorClass` and `CodeBlockTask` in it as described in the link.

Then I modified the code to display some message so that I know it worked or not

```
actorSystem.scheduler.schedule(initialDelay = 10.seconds, interval = 1.minute) {
    // the block of code that will be executed
    Logger.info("Executing something...")
    println("Executing something...")
  }
```

I ran the app through `sbt run` and *Executing something...* didn't display on console. 
These are my questions regarding it:
**1.** Does the job not get triggered after every minute by itself?
**2.** If not, how to properly trigger it?

Question regarding the whole situation:
**3.** What could I do if I want to apply the time based solution?
**P.S:** Solution in Scala is required.

Answer (score 0):

> I ran the app through sbt run and Executing something... didn't display on the console. These are my questions regarding it:
>
> 1. Does the job not get triggered after every minute by itself?
> 2. If not, how to properly trigger it?

The schedule that you used here:

```
actorSystem.scheduler.schedule(initialDelay = 10.seconds, interval = 1.minute) {
    // the block of code that will be executed
    Logger.info("Executing something...")
    println("Executing something...")
}
```

Here, you are adding an initial delay of `10 seconds` which means your actor will be scheduled after 10 seconds once your application is started at an interval of `1 minute`.

> 3. What could I do if I want to apply the time-based solution?

You can find the time-based solution to schedule Akka actor [here](https://github.com/tarangbhalodia/akka-scheduler-example/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/example/AkkaSchedulerExample.scala).